# the receiver doesn't still work after destroy android

Tags: android

when i destroy my app the logcat shows me this error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.examples.android.calendar.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.examples.android.calendar.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:20)
```

and i register my receiver like this :

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try{
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.v("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh", e.getMessage());
    }
}

 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();
    registerReceiver(
            this.mReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(
                    ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}
```

Comment: Your invalid logic located in AlarmReceiver class. LogCat show up it to you.

Comment: Really wish SO had a RTFL tag, just for Android.

Comment: The log says the error is inside the onReceive, please copy that code and say which line is 20.